# How can I use a fieldset with a custom form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to make a collapsible fieldset in a model. When I apply the fieldset it create a problem with some of the fields above. The problem is because I have some fields that are foriegn keys with a custom autocomplete form. And when I add these feilds to the fieldset they do not have the form which is needed.

I have tried:

```
fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('autocomplete_field_1', 'autocomplete_field_2', 'field_3'),
        }),
        ('advanced', {
            'classes': ('collapse',),
            'fields': ('field_4', 'field_5'),
        }),
    )
```

And I have tried only having the advanced fieldset, but that will not display autocomplete_field_1, autocomplete_field_2 or field 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a solution for this exact problem. I did however find a solution for anyone else having a similar problem.

The solution I ended up doing was essentially created a custom fieldset. It works by adding a checkbox in a custom form that would link to a JavaScript function.

```
from django.forms import CheckboxInput
class modelForm():
     checkbox = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=CheckboxInput(attrs={'onclick':'hide_field()'}), )
```

Then with this checkbox, I included a JavaScript file in the admin class, which contained this function. So now I have a checkbox that will hide and show fields based on the value.